# HTML Table with 2 (two) rows set beside a 4 (four) row set

Tags: html, html-table

How would I achieve this table layout?
[image]

Comment: I tried with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rows Demo </title>
<style>
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
     <td rowspan=2>Something</td>
     <td rowspan=2>Something more</td>
     <td>LastColumn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Column3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td rowspan=2>Something</td>
     <td rowspan=2>Something more</td>
     <td>LastColumn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Column3</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```